# WinSock: how to change TCP Acknowledge Frequency programmatically

Tags: tcp, winsock

The Windows registry has a key TcpAckFrequency (default 2), which sets the number of TCP packets received before sending back an ACK packet. Also, there is a TcpDelAckTicks key defining the delay (default 2 i.e. 2 * 100 ms = 200 ms) after which an acknowledgment is sent anyway, even if TcpAckFrequency is not reached.

Is there any way to change (temporarily) these parameters using WinSock API or other APIs, but without modifying the registry?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: not really the ack-frequency, you could en/disable the Nagle algorithm with setsockopt,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I am already disabling the Nagle algorithm, and it looks like it makes no difference for my particular problem (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747777/bsd-sockets-setsockopt-option-to-avoid-waiting-for-acknowledge-before-next-send)).

Comment: It's a global setting and will have 'effects' on other apps.

Comment: You don't want to mess around with stuff like this.